# How to read a multiline text file that only prints out the lines of the text file that contains integers?

Tags: python

I want to write a program that only print out lines of the text file that contain integers

Example input:

```
This line does not have any integers
P3rhaps th3re are some in this one
Definitely none in this line
This is the 4th line
```

Expected output

```
P3rhaps th3re are some in this one
This is the 4th line
```

Comment: could you post what code have you written so far? or where are you failing?

Comment: `with open('numbers.txt') as f:`
        
`output = [x.strip('\n') for x in f if any(c.isnumeric() for c in x)]`


`output `

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension in the loop of the open() by assigning any line containing any numeric character to a list.

```
    with open('a.txt') as f:
        output = [x.strip('\n') for x in f if any(c.isnumeric() for c in x)]

    output
```

Output

```
    ['P3rhaps th3re are some in this one', 'This is the 4th line']
```

Comment: I tried that and i get no out put im using repl.it to program and nothing will show up when i run the code it's just blank.

Comment: Nvm i fixed it thanks for the help i just added print(output)